# Use ES6 import with CoffeeScript and Browserify

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, browserify, es6-module-loader

CoffeeScript doesn't support ES6 `import` yet. (See https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3162)

I tried to use the following syntax as explained in the link:

```
`import { createAction, handleAction, handleActions } from 'redux-actions'`
```

But Browserify throws the following error:

```
Browerify { err: 
   { [Error: Parsing file: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (2:0)]
```

So, I'm currently stuck with the old traditional way:

```
reduxActions = require 'redux-actions'
console.log reduxActions.createAction
```

Which works fine but force me to either use `reduxActions.createAction` or to manually define `createAction = reduxActions.createAction` in each file were I need it. I'm looking for a better way of doing this, if any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A collegue of mine found a solution:

`{ createAction, handleAction, handleActions }  = require 'redux-actions'`

It's the best way of doing this I've found so far, looks like ES6.